# How small the value of float64 can support with?

Tags: go, floating-point, precision

I get data from an api request and perform a calculation based on the value.

Let say my bank account or crypto account have a balance of `301.38481999999999`

I want to withdraw all of the money, but the `float64` variable in golang automatically round up the variable to `301.38482` which caused the withdrawal operation to fail because I do not have that much money in my account.

```
package main

import(
    "log"
)

func main(){

    var myvar float64

    myvar = 301.38481999999999
    log.Println(myvar)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BXk9fcVJZVn

It show

```
301.38482
```

How can I get the exact balance with exact number so that I can withdraw all of it?

Comment: A float64 is an [IEEE 754-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) standard. Never use floating point for exact decimal values, like currency.

Comment: @JimB except that this is crypto, not dollars and cents, so fixed-point won't work.

Comment: Then you have to work within the constraints of floating point arithmetic. How do you have a `float64` value of `301.38481999999999` when that value is not representable as a double precision float? If you need arbitrary precision floats, use `math/big`.

Comment: yeah it is crypto where i do not know how much is the decimal places

Comment: "it is crypto" does not describe the types and data you are working with. To answer your exact question, the smallest subnormal double precision float is approximately 4.9406564584124654 × 10^−324, and the smallest normal positive double is approx 2.2250738585072014 × 10^−308, but this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: It seems like the actual problem here is that you're assuming what you see printed by `log.Println(myvar)` is the full precision of the value, which it isn't. [Per the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/), the default precision is 6 places.

Comment: Package math contains the relevant data.

Comment: Whether you are dealing with traditional currency or cryptocurrency, it is denominated in some units. The units might nominally be “dollars” or “bitcoins,” but the actual unit used in transactions is some smaller indivisible unit like cents or Satoshi (ten billions of a bitcoin). Scale your measurements to be that smaller unit. Then both integer and floating-point types can represent that unit without error, up until the number of units exceeds their precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the output you see with the actual value you have. If you [check the docs of `fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> For floating-point values, width sets the minimum width of the field and precision sets the number of places after the decimal, if appropriate, except that for %g/%G precision sets the maximum number of significant digits (trailing zeros are removed). For example, given 12.345 the format %6.3f prints 12.345 while %.3g prints 12.3. The default precision for %e, %f and %#g is 6; for %g it is the smallest number of digits necessary to identify the value uniquely.

`fmt.Println` always uses the default precision for whatever value you pass in. To see more precision, specify more precision:

```
var myvar float64
myvar = 301.38481999999999
log.Printf("%.20f", myvar)

// 301.38481999999999061401
```

https://play.golang.org/p/T4iyQcHY4qi

Regardless of what's printed, all internal arithmetic will be done with the full precision of the value. If you need more precision than float64 provides, see the `math/big` package.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Is there away to print the string as it is (301.38481999999999) without knowing how much the floating point places? because the value are retreived from API and I might not know the exact floating places of the value

Comment: No, because it's not a string. It's a decimal representation of a floating-point number, and not all decimal representations translate perfectly to binary representations; there will almost always be some inaccuracy in that conversion.

Comment: If you're receiving it from the API as a string, you should keep it as a string rather than converting to float, unless you need to do math on it, in which case you'll have to contend with floating-point precision.